# App Design - Engagement Type selected at beginning, or Radio buttons mid-request?

Tags: design, user-experience, ui, flow

I am building an app wherein a user will be requesting one of three engagement types:

- Appointment (no SLA)
- Consult (2hr SLA)
- Emergency (10mins SLA)

We are considering two different scenarios for submission of the desired request:

- Option 1 - At the beginning
- Option 2 - In the middle

**Option 1:**

User opens app with three buttons:

Engagement Types:

- 1-Appointment
- 2-Consult
- 3-Emergency

Next screen requires inputs:
Enter Patient Details (Name, ID, Reason for Request)

- Click NEXT

User will then see the next screen with the option to add images of injury or chart -

- If user selected Engagement Type 1 - Click NEXT (only option beyond image captures)
- If user selected Engagement Type 2 - Text Box will be available to enter consult request detail - Click SUBMIT CONSULT REQUEST
- If user selected Engagement Type 3 - Click SUBMIT EMERGENCY CALLBACK (will auto-send sms to on-call individual with Requestor Name, Patient Name, Reason for Request)

Engagement Type 1 Continued:

User will see a screen with an auto-generated Appointment Location/Date/Time

**-----END OF REQUEST-----**

**Option 2:**

User opens app with one button: Start Request

Next screen requires inputs:
Enter Patient Details (Name, ID, Reason for Request)
Select Engagement Type:

- 1- Appointment
- 2- Consult
- 3- EMERGENCY
- Click NEXT

Next screen has option to add images of injury or chart and different option depending on Engagement Type:

- If Engagement Type 1 screen: Click NEXT (only option beyond image captures)
- If Engagement Type 2 screen: Text Box will be available to enter consult request detail - Click SUBMIT CONSULT REQUEST (auto-sends SMS with Requestor Name, Patient Name, Reason for Consult)
- If Engagement Type 3 screen: Click SUBMIT EMERGENCY CALLBACK  (will auto-send sms to on-call individual with Requestor Name, Patient Name, Reason for Request)

Engagement Type 1 Continued:

1 - Appointment: User will see a screen with an auto-generated Appointment Location/Date/Time

**-----END OF REQUEST-----**

Basically, is it better practice to have the user select the type of request up front, or to simplify with one button initiation and multiple radio buttons after the required inputs are completed?

Comment: From an engineering standpoint, neither option is clearly better. For a UX standpoint, you could ask at our sister site [ux.se]. Be sure to read their help center for asking a good question.

Comment: The decision that needs to be made here is not one for a software developer, it's one for a product owner (or UX specialist - but ultimately it's the PO that signs off). The question is posted in the wrong place.